# Debugging node.js microservices behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, debugging, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've been struggling for a few days to get remote debugging of node.js working on Google Container Engine via Kubernetes.
The main issue comes from the fact that the services that I want to debug are behind an nginx reverse proxy.

So my question is, first of all, is it possible to remotely debug upstream services that lie behind a reverse proxy?
And if so, how?

If I could get debugging working through reverse proxy on localhost I'm fairly confident that I could get it working on gke through Kubernetes too.

I'd be happy to supply you with any information you need, like configs etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to get debugging working through the nginx reverse proxy and instead just settled with debugging single kubernetes pods (docker droplets) through port-forwarding from the specific pod to my localhost, and then just attach the debugger to localhost:PORT

Here's the command and [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_port-forward/) in case someone needs it:

```
kubectl port-forward POD-NAME PORT
```

And you get the POD-NAME by running the following command:

```
kubectl get pods
```